# Generalized Collatz: divide out by $2$’s and $3$'s, otherwise $5n+1?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, recursion, collatz-conjecture

One direction of generalizing Collatz is, instead of dividing out by the smallest prime $2$, to divide out by the first two smallest primes $2, 3$ and then do $5n + 1$ instead of $3n + 1$. It seems that if we define the function

$f(n) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2}, & \text{if } 2 | n, \\
    \frac{n}{3}, & \text{if } 2 \nmid n \text{ and } 3 | n, \\
    5n+1, &\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$

then $f(n)$ falls fairly quickly into the $\{1, 3, 6\}$-loop for small values of $n$. For instance, the trajectory for $n = 5$ is $$5 \to 26 \to 13 \to 66 \to 33 \to 11 \to 56 \to 28 \to 14 \to 7 \to 36 \to 18 \to 9 \to 3 \to 1,$$ whereupon it cycles endlessly. In fact, in this loop one can readily see convergence will happen for all $n < 17$, and for $n = 17$, the cycle goes $$17 \to 86 \to 43 \to 216 \to ... \to 1.$$

It seems that this converges rather quickly, and a similar generalization dividing out by $2, 3, 5$ or else doing a $7n+1$ step would seem to converge even faster. For large values of $k$, the function dividing out by all primes $2$ through $p_k$ and otherwise doing a $(p_{k+1})n+1$ step would seem absurdly unlikely to enter a nontrivial cycle, much less escape to infinity.

**Have these generalizations been studied? Are results known? Is convergence established for one or more of them, perhaps for $k$ quite large?**

Comment: Well, this has been studied, but I only have seen discussions considering this scattered over the internet; no deeper analyses are known to me (but which might not mean much... ;-) ). Unfortunately I wouldn't know an effective search-pattern...

Comment: I found this [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/papers/2004/2004-lesjohn.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwimpPbP1PLrAhVSsKQKHShIAgUQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw29aGMbO5OI6DrMNvV7L-3y) "On a Generalization of the Collatz Conjecture" by John Lesieutre.

Comment: @BillyJoe Oh nice! I see that they describe a cycle $17 \to 47 \to 37 \to 17$ when $p_{k+1} = 11$ as well.

Comment: @RiversMcForge The table on the very last page of that paper may interest you. In particular it notes the cycle $7\ \rightarrow\ 309\ \rightarrow\ 7$ for $k=3275$.

Comment: What, is the original problem not difficult enough? ;)